# How to get version information of an included library?

Tags: java, android, manifest

I have an eclipse project with two included library projects. These projects have their own manifest files with version information. Now I want to read the version number from these library projects within my main project. The information can't be read by calling the PackageManager:

```
//Get the version name from the included library project
String libVersion  = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.zxing.client.android", 0).versionName;
```

Because the library is not an installed application. But what's the right way to get these information?

For instance: I have included zxing Android project as library project. These Project has following version information in its manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.zxing.client.android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="88"
    android:versionName="4.3.2" >
```

I want to read versionCode and versionName. If I use packageManager like in the coding above, I will get versionCode "93" and versionName "4.5".

Comment: You can see the version in the name itself..

Comment: If you have the source code of library project,for a workaround, why not add an interface in that library which returns the version?

Comment: Both doesn't work. The AndroidManifest.xml of the library project isn't part of the apk, so I think the version information of the library project will get lost at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it **is** possible now (maybe due to new API changes, tested with API 17 (calling project), API 14 (library project)): if you specifically call the correct package name it will retrieve version information from that packages Manifest file:

eg:

```
String versionName = getPackageManager().
        getPackageInfo("PACKAGE_FROM_WHICH_TO_RETRIEVE_MANIFEST", 0).versionName;
```

Comment: This did not work for me, returning an exception since the library is not an installed package of reference.

Comment: JCricket: did you add the JAR file (library) to the buildpath of the main project and tick it in "order & export", then did a project->clean? i'm working with eclipse, not sure how it works in other IDEs

Comment: I was in Android Studio, so the order & export option was not available. I had posted an answer here, but a moderator deleted it....Not sure why. See here for what worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30584970/1544046