# Get version information of an included library?

Tags: android

I have created 2 project 1 is Lib and 2nd in Test.
From test app I pass context to Lib project.

As I have context in Lib, i used below code inside Lib

String version = this.mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.mContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
Log.e("versionName", version);

But this gives me version name of test app and not lib.
How should i get application version name and code for Lib?

Reference link:
[How to get version information of an included library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399837/how-to-get-version-information-of-an-included-library)

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399837/how-to-get-version-information-of-an-included-library/29698415#29698415

Answer (score 14):

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
```

Just make sure that you import the BuildConfig for your library (as literally every android library/app has it's own BuildConfig on it's package path). The Android Studio's Gradle Build system indicates that this is always generated as of version 0.7.0 (see [changelog](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)).

Comment: Worth pointing out that `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` and `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` are [no longer available in the Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#version_properties_removed_from_buildconfig_class_in_library_projects).